Why is it said that inductor absorbs reactive power and capacitor delivers reactive power?
It is said that reactive power is that power that oscillates between the source and the load. The reactive power stored by an inductor or capacitor is supplied back to the source by it. So, since both the inductor and capacitor are storing as well as delivering (releasing) the energy back to the source, why is it said that inductor absorbs reactive power and capacitor delivers reactive power?

Whoever said that is either being misrepresented by your good self or, it comes from a dodgy place.

@Andyaka It's a pretty common sign convention in the electrical industry that capacitive loads produce vars, while inductive loads consume or absorb vars. Consider e.g. the term 'static VAR generator'.

It's specifically about balancing loads for controlling site power factor.  If you have both L and C loads the stored energy will to some extent oscillate between them and not leave the site. This reduces  losses and avoids overloading the distribution equipment.  The source and sink is just a way to make the math easy in the field.

@SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica it's all about context; the op assumed we would understand the context and you are guessing the real context. Either way, without context, it makes a weak question.

As a power system engineer working with high voltage equipment in the mega watt range I must say: This question makes perfect sense to me and I find it unambiguous. I would say OP's mistake here is assuming that those working with electronics use the same terminology as "we" do. I've made the same mistake on this site several times myself.

FWIW As an essentially  non power system engineer working with much of some stuff and a little of many things the question easily made enough sense to me to be able to be interacted with. I won't as others have dome so well enough. I see someone has downvoted the question. I'd not personally have felt that appropriate, but I'm aware that others may. I've upvoted it.

Whoever said that is misunderstanding what conventional reactive power and its sign convention means. Conventional reactive power does not mean the same thing as energy.
Typically, uncorrected low power factor loads tend to be inductive, so motors, fluorescent ballasts and the like. This is bad, as it draws more current through the network than would be needed to deliver the same real power. This is why it has perhaps been given the convention that this load is consuming reactive power.
The user can fix the 'import' of reactive power by adding capacitive devices which by convention are said to 'generate' reactive power.
It is worth giving these two types of loads signs, as when the amount of reactive power of each is equal, the site presents a power factor of 1.0 to the grid, the two reactive powers add to zero.
In practice, we know that both inductive and capacitive devices are receiving energy during one half cycle, and releasing it back the other half cycle. It's the timing of this energy storage and release within the mains cycle that controls the sign of the convention for reactive power. Conventional reactive power does not mean the same thing as energy.

(we know I don't - isn't that quarter cycles?)

Industry convention assigns a sign to the direction of reactive power. That convention is that an inductive load consumes both real power (Watts) and reactive power (VARs), while a capacitive load consumes real power but generates reactive power.
This 'convention' is set in many metering and measurement standards, and while it is possible to ignore it, it may cause confusion in much the same way as refusing to use conventional current.
See for example this Schneider FAQ demonstrating the four quadrants of power transfer:

Note that while IEC and IEEE disagree on the sign of power factor in some cases, both agree that an inductor has watts positive and vars positive.
A similar disambiguation document is available in NZ's Measurement Standards Laboratory Technical Guide 28, which cites IEC 61268 and BS EN 62053-23.

Incorrect, but sometimes used.
You have to slap an arbitrary sign to either type of load and the other will be the opposite sign.
Usually, the inductive load is considered as a sink and capacitive as a source of the reactive power.
It probably comes from the heavy motor dominated industrial load that tends to be inductive. A/C units from the recent past in the residental grids were inductive as well.
You can go the other way round as long as the next guy understands what you are saying.

While you're correct that it's arbitrary, the industry has very clearly settled on a sign convention - it's necessary given that almost every electrical system bills some customers for VARs and some probably even have dispatchable reactance.

@SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica, I used to be responsible for energy metering in a factory but that was one thing I never figured out. If the power factor went very capacitive (< 0.95) would the utility company not charge for that too? i.e., Are they only concerned about the absolute value?

@Transistor It depends on the utility but in most cases they don't care about capacitive power factors. My local lines company (Wellington Electricity) will charge commercial customers a fee if their "power factor is less than 0.95 lagging" - but only if they don't have a kVA demand charge.

Hopefully you know the complex phasor calculation method for linear circuits which work at single frequency and have sinusoidal voltages and currents.
There one can use formula S = UI* (where the I* means the conjugate of the phasor of the current) to find the complex power S = P + Qj where P is the real power and Q is the reactive power. When the polarities of the phasors U and I are selected in the common way i.e. so that a resistive load would sink positive P from a voltage source, the reactive power would be positive for inductive loads and negative for capacitive loads.
It's only a habit to say that an inductor absorbs reactive power. It's convenient, because formula S = UI* gives the real power and reactive power both as positive when one feeds energy dissipating inductive load from a voltage source. The convenience is that one can think the formula of the the complex power presents both components of the power fed to the load.
Accordingly it's as convenient to think a capacitive load outputs reactive power. But actually reactive power is not produced nor absorbed. It is a measure for oscillation where energy flows to both directions. If you search older discussions about reactive power you'll find the exact relation between the reactive power and how much energy the load stores temporarily to fields and returns back to the source. Search for "what exactly is reactive power in concrete terms".
